# JFrame.setVisible(true) keeps iterating it's parent method until a stackOverflowError occurs

Tags: java, swing

I've got a JFrame subclass which waits for a specific console input before displaying a JFrame and its contained widgets using the setVisible(true) method. The widgets (which are a subclass of JPanels) are added to the parent JFrame from a LinkedList using an iterator, and are added to the LinkedList via another method in the class.

When I run the program, it keeps repeating the method which contains this.setVisible(true), and doesn't display anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've pasted the code below.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{

class KPanel extends JPanel{        //virtual class for Panels that displayed variable name in titled border 
    public KPanel(String varName){
        TitledBorder varTitle = new TitledBorder(varName +":");
        this.setBorder(varTitle);       
    }
}

private LinkedList<KPanel> buffer; //list containing components to be added to GUI

public GUI(String title){
    setTitle(title);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setSize(300,300);       
    buffer = new LinkedList<KPanel>(); //initializes linkedlist buffer
}

public void addBox(String var, String val){

//creates a panel containing a string, adds it to the buffer

    KPanel temp = new KPanel(var);
    JLabel valLabel = new JLabel(val);
    temp.add(valLabel);
    buffer.add(temp);
}



public void show(){

    int i=0; 
    int wid_height;
    int x = 0;
    if ((x = buffer.size()) != 0)
        wid_height = this.getHeight()/x; //calculates widget heights for even distribution along frame
    else{
        System.out.println("No variables set!");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("buffer: " + buffer.size() + "\nheights: " + wid_height);


    Iterator<KPanel>  iter = buffer.iterator();
    KPanel temp = new KPanel("");

    while(iter.hasNext()){
        temp = iter.next();
        temp.setSize(this.getWidth(), wid_height);
        temp.setLocation(0, wid_height*i);
        this.add(temp);
        i++;
    }

    this.setVisible(true);
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: The stack trace should tell you what happens: setVisible() calls show(), which calls setVisible(), etc.

Comment: Another reason to avoid inheritance when possible -- unsuspecting method overrides. A similar thing happened to me when my class extended JPanel and had a `getX()` and `getY()` method. The solution: don't override JFrame unless you've got a very good reason to do so.

Answer (score 6):

Your `show()` method is overriding an existing method in `JFrame`. Use a different name, or, better yet, don't extend `JFrame` unless you really need to change how a frame behaves.

Comment: Ahh thanks, I changed the method to "render" instead. It works!!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `show()` method is overriding the `show()` method in `JFrame`.  What leads to the `StackOverflowError` is that it's calling `setVisible(true)`.  This method is inherited from `Component`, and it is simple.  [Here's the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Component.java#Component.setVisible%28boolean%29):

```
public void setVisible(boolean b) {
    show(b);
}
```

and [`show(b)` calls `show()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Component.java#Component.show%28boolean%29):

```
public void show(boolean b) {
    if (b) {
        show();
    } else {
        hide();
    }
}
```

So, your `show` calls `setVisible`, which calls your `show`, with nothing to break the cycle.  I would use a different name for your `show` method to prevent this infinite loop.